Not Available: Build and push an image to Azure Container Registry task
I have my code repository in AzureDevOps. I would like create an image and push to the registry using build pipeline but I am unable to find the task or template.
any inputs on it?
I can see below tasks only and Docker Task is not available.

Expected one:


try creating pipeline from repo. Where your files are. I have never used Start Right Option in my devops. I am not sure about it.
if you still do not find docker task, try selecting starter pipeline option and in top right corner show assistant option you can use it to add additional task. you may find it there image

Have you tried as the steps shared in my answer below? Is it working for you? @BalanjaneyuluK

To build and push Docker image to ACR (Azure Container Registry), you can do like as below:

On Azure Portal, create an ACR under your Azure subscription and Resource group if you do not have one.


In Azure DevOps project where you need to set up and run the pipeline, go to "Project Settings" > "Service connections" to create a Docker Registry service connection if you do not have one. Provide the valid authentication information so that it can connect and access to your ACR.


In the pipeline, you can use the Docker task to build and push the image to ACR.
# azure-pipelines.yml

variables:
  dockerConnection: 'BrightRanACR'
  repositoryName: 'myubuntu2204'
  dockerfilePath: './Ubuntu2204.Dockerfile'

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: 'Build & Push image to ACR'
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: '$(dockerConnection)'
    repository: '$(repositoryName)'
    command: 'buildAndPush'
    Dockerfile: '$(dockerfilePath)'
    tags: |
      $(Build.BuildId)
      latest





When you create the pipeline:

If you do not have an existing YAML file (azure-pipelines.yml), you can select "Starter pipeline" option. It will create a initialize YAML file, you can copy the content shared above into the YAML file to overwrite the initialize content and replace the values of variables with your actual ones.

If you have an existing initialize YAML file, you can select "Existing Azure Pipelines YAML file" option and then select the existing YAML file. Then copy above content into the YAML file to overwrite the initialize content and replace the variable values.



